# triple type casting bit work - widening from char to long

Tags: java, types, casting

I'm trying to figure out the **bit casting** in the line below:

```
long a = (long) (int) (char) (-2)
```

I want to represent it as an hex number

what comes before what?

i've tried to cast from right to left so i just padded with 1's and the result is: `0xfffffffe`

I know that the output is fffe but why (O_o)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did not get what you meant in this line "I know that the output is fffe but why (O_o)? ". Could you elaborate. Are you not getting the output as 0xfffe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thats my example-code:

```
// equal to question
long a = (long) ((int) ((char) (-2)));

//printing partial solutions
int number = -2;
char c = (char)number;
int i = (int)c;
long l = (long)i;

System.out.printf("number: %08x\n", number);
System.out.printf("char: %08x\n", (int)c); //cast to print
System.out.printf("int: %08x\n", i);
System.out.printf("long: %08x\n", l);
```

Output:

```
number: fffffffe
char: 0000fffe
int: 0000fffe
long: 0000fffe
```

An int has 4 Byte, a char has 2 Byte and a long has 8 Byte.

Every 0.5 Bytes are one hexnumber [0 to f] == [0 to 15].
(2 hex-numbers are 1 Byte.)

A cast don't convert a number from one range to an other. It cuts of the Byte (bit) from the given value to the range from the new value.
(If you're cast from a biger range to a smaler.)

What happens?

-2 is per default an int. You're cast to char (from 4 Byte to 2 Byte). The fist 2 Byte will cut of. So You're result is 0xfffe.
Than you're casting to bigger ranges and zeros are add. (Nothing will change.)

So, that's the reason why -2 will be 0xfffe (as number: 65534) after the three casts.

Comment: This is [*Java*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html); `char` is 2 bytes, `int` is 4 bytes and `long` is 8 bytes.

Comment: Java specifies widths and conversion rules for all the primitive types.

Comment: sorry correct, i will solve the failor

Comment: Thank you very much Uwe. But I've seen your output and i wanted to check if i've fully understand: when you casting from int to char so the bits are just fffe not 0000fffe correct?

Comment: correct. my print looks like '0000fffe' because i say in printf '%08x'. so printf writes the given parameter as hex with 8 characters. if you want to see 'fffe', you need to change the line into -> System.out.printf("char: %04x\n", (int)c);